# Powershell - SET-ADUSER Modify samaccountname

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

New to powershell and still trying to get the logic.

I would like to filter out the samaccountname's in active directory in a specific OU, that also contain "adm" at the end of the string (phil_test_adm). When the users are found i want to replace with the "adm" with "tst". So far i have the below, again i am struggerling with the logic.

```
import-module activedirectory
$Path = 'OU=Example, OU=Users,DC=uk,DC=random,DC=com'
$users = Get-ADUser -filter 'SamAccountName -like "*adm"' -SearchBase $Path | select-object samaccountname, name
#foreach ($user in $users) 
#{
#Set-ADUser $user.samaccountname -Replace { 
#if $user.sammaccountname -eq "*adm"  }
```

As you can see where foreach begins i have just been playing about.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why do you have "if $user.sammaccountname -eq "*adm"" at the bottom when your results stored in $users have already been filtered on adm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your first few lines are working to retrieve the correct results, this foreach block should work:

```
foreach ($user in $users) 
{
    $newSamAccoutname = $user.SamAccountName.replace("adm","tst")
    Set-ADUser $user -Replace @{samaccountname=$newSamAccoutname} 
}
```

Comment: Wow.. not hard really when you think about it! thank you for the input very helpful! now just to put in some error handling :) cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {Set-ADUser $user -samaccountname $($user.SamAccountName -replace 'adm$','tst')}
```